# sorted a dictionary into a list and need to print out the list in a specific format in Python 3.5.2

Tags: list, python-3.x, dictionary, formatting, format

I have a file that I read in and store the individual words in a list. I then modify the list by removing the punctuation, whitespace, newlines, etc. Then I take this list, run them into a dictionary to keep the frequency of each word.

With this completed, I have an unsorted list of words whose frequency is known, so I use `sorted()` to put them in order from lowest to highest frequency. To use the sorted, I put the output into a list.

The format of this list is now `[(word, frequency),(word_2, frequency),(word_3, frequency),...(word_N, frequency)]`, with each word being a unique and the frequency differing for each word.

**Question**

Is there a way to grab both of those values (word and frequency) and output them in this format being "word - frequency"?

Comment: `print('\n'.join(["{} - {}".format(w, f) for w,f in your_sorted_list]))`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
for i in freq_list:
    print("%s - %d"%i)
```